# How do you manually compute for silhouette, cohesion and separation of Cluster

Tags: validation, cluster-analysis, cohesion

Good day!

I have been looking all over the Internet on how to compute for silhouette coefficient, cohesion and separation unfortunately, despite the resources, I just can't understand the formulas posted. I know that there are implementations of it in some tool, but I want to know how to manually compute them especially given a vector space model.

#### Assuming that I have the following clusters:

Cluster 1 ={{1,0},{1,1}} 
Cluster 2 ={{1,2},{2,3},{2,2},{1,2}}, 
Cluster 3 ={{3,1},{3,3},{2,1}}

#### The way I understood it according to [1] is that I have to get the average of the points per cluster:

C1 X = 1; Y = .5
C2 X = 1.5; Y = 2.25
C3 X = 2.67; Y = 1.67

#### Given the mean, I have to compute for my cohesion by Sum of Square Error (SSE):

Cohesion(C1) = (1-1)^2 + (1-1)^2 + (0-.5)^2 + (0-.5)^2 = *0.5* 
Cohesion(C2) = (1-1.5)^2 + (2-1.5)^2 + (2-1.5)^2 + (1-1.5)^2 + (2-2.5)^2 + (3-2.5)^2 + (2-2.5)^2 +(2-2.5)^2 = *2* 
Cohesion(C3) = (3-2.67)^2 + (3-2.67)^2 + (2-2.67)^2 + (1-1.67)^2 + (3-1.67)^2 + (1-1.67)^2 = *3.3334*

Cluster(C) = 0.5 + 2 + 3.3334 = *5.8334*

**My questions are:** 

1. Did I perform cohesion correctly? 
2. How do I compute for Separation? 
3. How do I compute for Silhouette Coefficient?

Thank you.

**References:**
 [1] http://www.cs.kent.edu/~jin/DM08/ClusterValidation.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computation of Silhouette is straightforward, but it does not involve the centroids.

So don't try to compute it from what you did for cohesion; compute it from your original data.

Answer (score 13):

```
Cluster 1 ={{1,0},{1,1}} 
Cluster 2 ={{1,2},{2,3},{2,2},{1,2}}, 
Cluster 3 ={{3,1},{3,3},{2,1}}
```

Take a point `{1,0} in cluster 1`

Calculate its **average distance** to all other points in **it’s cluster**, i.e. cluster 1

```
So a1 =√( (1-1)^2 + (0-1)^2) =√(0+1)=√1=1
```

Now for the object {1,0} in cluster 1 calculate its average distance from all the objects in cluster 2 and cluster 3. Of these take the **minimum** average distance.

So for cluster 2

```
{1,0} ----> {1,2} = distance = √((1-1)^2 + (0-2)^2) =√(0+4)=√4=2
{1,0} ----> {2,3} = distance = √((1-2)^2 + (0-3)^2) =√(1+9)=√10=3.16
{1,0} ----> {2,2} = distance = √((1-2)^2 + (0-2)^2) =√(1+4)=√5=2.24
{1,0} ----> {1,2} = distance = √((1-1)^2 + (0-2)^2) =√(0+4)=√4=2
```

Therefore, the average distance of point {1,0} in cluster 1 to all the points in cluster 2 =

`(2+3.16+2.24+2)/4 = 2.325`

Similarly, for cluster 3

```
{1,0} ----> {3,1} = distance = √((1-3)^2 + (0-1)^2) =√(4+1)=√5=2.24
{1,0} ----> {3,3} = distance = √((1-3)^2 + (0-3)^2) =√(4+9)=√13=3.61
{1,0} ----> {2,1} = distance = √((1-2)^2 + (0-1)^2) =√(1+1)=√2=2.24
```

Therefore, the **average distance** of point {1,0} in cluster 1 to all the points in cluster 3 =

`(2.24+3.61+2.24)/3 = 2.7`

Now, the **minimum** average distance of the point {1,0} in cluster 1  to the other clusters 2 and 3 is,

`b1 =2.325` (2.325 < 2.7)

So the silhouette coefficient of cluster 1

`s1= 1-(a1/b1) = 1- (1/2.325)=1-0.4301=0.5699`

In a similar fashion you need to calculate the silhouette coefficient for cluster 2 and cluster 3 separately by taking any single object point in each of the clusters and repeating the steps above. Of these the cluster with the greatest silhouette coefficient is the best as per evaluation.

*Note: The distance here is the Euclidean Distance!* You can also have a look at this video for further explanation:

https://www.coursera.org/learn/cluster-analysis/lecture/RJJfM/6-2-clustering-evaluation-measuring-clustering-quality

Comment: Good explanation! BTW, small correction:
As per the original paper, the formula for SC is = (b - a) / max(b,a)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_jg1UFoef1c    : This is another good resource to check.

Answer (score 0):

As you have calculated the Cohesion of C1, there is a mistake.

```
Cohesion(C1) = (1 - 1) ^ 2 + (1 - 1) ^ 2 + (0 - .5) ^ 2 + (1 - .5) ^ 2 = 0.5
```

This is the **Prototype-Based** (**Centroid** in this case) Cohesion calculation.

**For calculating Separation**: {Between clusters i.e. (C1,C2) , (C1,C3) & (C2,C3)}

```
Separation(C1,C2) = SSE(Centroid(C1), Centroid(C2))
= (1 - 1.5) ^ 2 + (0.5 - 2.25) ^ 2 = 1 + 3.0625 = 4.0625
```

**Silhouette Coefficient:** Combines both the Cohesion and Separation.

Refer https://cs.fit.edu/~pkc/classes/ml-internet/silhouette.pdf

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer,
Calculate its average distance to all other points in its cluster, i.e. cluster 1'  --> This part has to be corrected.

So

```
a1 =√( (1-1)^2 + (0-1)^2) =√(0+1)=√1=1
```

Answer (score 0):

{1,0} ----> {2,1} = distance = √((1-2)^2 + (0-1)^2) =√(1+1)=√2=2.24

this is an error because the root of 2 is approximately 1.41